# How do I redirect URLS that begin with /test/ to a separate script?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an existing htaccess that works fine:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /default.php 
DirectoryIndex index.php /default.php
```

I wish to modify this so that all urls that start with /test/ go to /test/default.php.

Example: http://www.x.com/hello.php -- > http://www.x.com/default.php
Example: http://www.x.com/test/hello.php -- > http://www.x.com/test/default.php

Comment: sorry, wasn't specific enough. I want links other than the /test/ links to keep going to the original script.

Comment: In the second example do you need to keep the 'hello.php' information?

Answer (score 3):

Basically, just put `/test/` in front of your expression. Also, the parentheses are unnecessary here:

```
RewriteRule ^/test/ /test/default.php
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass on information from the URL you can capture it (with parentheses) and send it to default.php  (with $1) as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^/test/(.*)$ /test/default.php/$1
```

so that http//..../test/foo/bar/ would result in /test/default.php/foo/bar/ . Your script can then access the extra information.

Answer (score 0):

I’d use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]*/)*
RewriteRule !/default\.php$ %0default.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/test(/.*)?$ /test/default.php [L]
```

Access the original URI, if needed, in the $_SERVER global array.

Judging by your original, you probably want:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/test(/.*)?$ /test/default.php [L]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /default.php
```